# Reporting services node disabled in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssms, ssrs-2012

Why reporting services node is disabled in the object explorer of my SSMS ?

[image: Reporting services disabled]

Answer (score 0):

> SSMSE cannot manage Analysis Services, Integration Services, or
>   Reporting Services.

More information: https://technet.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/ms365247%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Problem is with your Express version of SSMS

Answer (score 0):

@Krtrek is correct. However, you can install the most recent SSMS preview release to connect to Analysis Services, Integration Services, Database Services, and Reporting Services engines. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt238290.aspx